# how to fetch tweet from twitter without login?

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch tweet from twitter without login only passing username.is it possible or not?. so please help me. advance in thanks.

Comment: "all tweet from twitter" => that's a lot !

Comment: How do you know what user to get tweets for without any reference to said user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Link And Do Json Parsing

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name= your username

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible without logging-in to twitter.

twitter authentication is standard and proper logging-in is required.